# How can I apply environment variables without reboot?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

Is there a way I can apply changes to environment variables without rebooting on Windows 7?

Comment: I think you can log off and log back on again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set an environment variable with the `SET` command in a command interpreter, it applies right there and then, to that process' environment.  No rebooting, no logging off and on — nothing more required.

[The environment variables that are held in the registry are not, in fact, environment variables at all.  They are a *template*.  Coöperating programs read from the template and create/modify their own *actual* environments from it.  They know when the template changes because there's a windows message that is broadcast to all top-level windows to say that this has happened.](https://serverfault.com/questions/241012)  You need to broadcast that message.  All coöperating programs, including Windows Explorer, will re-read the template and adjust their environments, that will be inherited by any new processes that they spawn from that point onwards, accordingly.

Comment: You are perfectly correct, however, some applications may need to be restarted - if they read (and cache) environment variables, they may not be aware of changes. But rarely should that ever mean that a reboot is required.

Comment: Restarting the program which was accessing the environment variable did the trick for me!